# Change a text view inside of the active dialog?

Tags: android

I got stuck with this problem probably because I'm not really well worded in the android framework's basic inner workings.

So I'm generating rows in a tablelayout, and these rows have an onclick action to open a dialog. The code looks like this:

```
titleText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_book);
                            dialog.setTitle("Update dialog");

                            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button

                            String sIsbn = "-";
                            if ( book.getIsbn() != null ) {
                                sIsbn = Long.toString(book.getIsbn());
                            }
                            TextView uIsbn = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Uisbn);
                            uIsbn.setText(sIsbn);
                            Button readBCode = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Uread);
                            readBCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
                                    integrator.initiateScan();
                                }
                            });
                            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Uclose);
                            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            dialog.show();
}
```

Here in the dialog I have a button called readBCode, when this is clicked, a barcode scanning starts and disappears when the barcode is retrieved:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                tToast("Cancelled");
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                tToast("Scanned: " + result.getContents());
                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView uIsbn = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Uisbn);
                uIsbn.setText(result.getContents());
            }
        } else {
            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to push back this resulting string that I have got into that active dialog's Isbn text view, BUT this of course fails... How should I proceed to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was inside of a Fragment, so I should have used `IntentIntegrator.forFragment` and that alone resolved it.